# Mongoose find date which is inside an array of values

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

Say, i have a mongoose model, the model has a date field, **it has an array of objects which again has dates for each.**

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
categoryName:{type: String},
points:[{
    criteria1:{type: Number},
    criteria2:{type: Number},
    pointedDate:{type: Date, default: Date.now}
}],
createdAt:{type: Date, default: Date.now};
})
```

**Note**: The points field keeps updating.

i want to find the list of **points** added in a specific month.

i know to sort dates of **createdAt** by how do i sort the dates which inside the array.

I have simplified my actual scenario, expecting to find date result inside that array.

Please help, its a very tricky one, tons of thanks in advance.